# In a shell script, process options like -a -b but leave --abc alone?

Tags: shell, getopts

So I have a shell script that does some preparation and then runs a utility.

The preparation can be affected by switches like `-a` or `-n`. The contents of the command line that are not such switches are to be passed to the utility. Currently my script has:

```
while getopts ":an" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      #something
      ;;
    n)
      #something else
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
  #more prep
my_utility $@
```

However, this fails when I want to pass long-form options to the utility, such as `--abc` as that is interpreted as `a`, `b`, and `c` options by getopts.

So how can I process options in such a way that `-a` or `-n` is processed, but `--abc` remains untouched? Unless, of course, I dump Shell and do it in Python - then options would be very easy, but I also need to copy files and run utilities, and Python makes this awkward.

Comment: getopts is not able to process double dash arguments

Comment: You could do this by copying the unrecognized options to a shell variable, and passing *that* to `my_utility`, but it requires keeping in mind special cases where the getopts parameter must handle options with values.

Comment: I disagree with "I also need to copy files and run utilities, and Python makes this awkward." Use [`shutil.copy2()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) for the former and [`subprocess.check_call([...])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) and [`subprocess.check_output([...])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) for the latter. In many cases you can still keep these as one-liners. And the language expressiveness you gain for the rest of the script is definitely worth it!

Answer (score 2):

To interpret double dash commands you need GNU's `getopt` instead of the built-in `getopts`.

There is a way to use the bash builtin `getopts` to mimic long options, but you should not do that as it's a kludge and not worth your effort as `getopts` cannot *enforce* the long specification.

So your script becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get options
OPTS=`getopt --options an: --long a_something,n_something_else: -n 'parse-options' -- "$@"`

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Failed parsing options." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

#echo parsed and cleaned up options
echo "$OPTS"
eval set -- "$OPTS"

bSomething=false
bSomethingElse=false

# "Endless" loop over the parsed options
while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -a | --a_something )       bSomething=true;     shift ;;
    -n | --n_something_else )  bSomethingElse=true; shift ;;
    -- )                                            shift; break ;;
    * )                                                    break ;;
  esac
done
```

For more information: [`man getopt`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt)
For even more information: [`man getopt(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt)

Comment: Thank you! But I dont understand how this works. The while loop just goes through $1 until $1 becomes unrecognizeable, I like this. But what does getopts do, as that loop does not invoke it?

Comment: @MikhailRamendik `getopts` parses the options, then prints them in a cleaned-up, standardized format. The `set` command then replaces the passed arguments with the cleaned-up version, so that the `while` loop can parse them easily.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for responding while I was asleep.  **;-)** Code edited to clarify as well.

Comment: getopt, unlike getopt**s**, is non-standard. also notice that getopt**s** is not just a "bash builtin", but a posix mandated utility, present in all shells on all modern systems.

Comment: also, getopt is not able to handle empty strings as argument values; example: `getopt aq: -q '' -a`

Comment: @mosvy The GNU version of `getopt` can handle empty strings *if* you use its nonstandard `-o` | `--options` option for the format string: `getopt -o aq: -- -q '' -a` prints " -q '' -a -- " (which, when double-quoted and `eval`ed, gives the correct result). Other versions of `getopt`... not so much.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you couldn't simulate long options by treating `-` as a short option requiring an argument:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo
while getopts :aq:-: opt; do
        case $opt in
        a)      echo option -a;;
        q)      echo option -q with value "$OPTARG";;
        -)      case $OPTARG in
                abc)    echo option --abc;;
                def=*)  echo option --def with value "${OPTARG#*=}";;
                *)      echo >&2 "unknown option --$OPTARG";;
                esac;;
        :)      echo >&2 "-$OPTARG needs an argument";;
        *)      echo >&2 "unknown option -$OPTARG";;
        esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"
echo argv: "$@"

$ sh /tmp/foo -a -qt --abc --def=ghi -- foo bar
option -a
option -q with value t
option --abc
option --def with value ghi
argv: foo bar
```

If you want to make a list of arguments (eg. to call another command with it), and your shell doesn't support arrays (eg. debian's or busybox's `/bin/sh`), you can use the following trick, which will pass to eval a list of argument indexes instead of actual strings; that will avoid any IFS splitting/globbing/whitespace annoyances:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo
# handle -a and -qval
# call another command with any long options and non-option arguments
av=
while getopts :aq:-: opt; do
        case $opt in
        a)      echo option -a;;
        q)      echo option -q with value "'$OPTARG'";;
        -)      av="$av \"\${$((OPTIND-1))}\"" ;; # pass long options unchanged
        :)      echo >&2 "-$OPTARG needs an argument";;
        *)      echo >&2 "unknown option -$OPTARG";;
        esac
done
i=$OPTIND; while [ "$i" -le "$#" ]; do av="$av \"\${$i}\"" i=$((i + 1)); done

print_its_args(){ for a; do printf ' {%s}' "$a"; done; echo; }
echo "print_its_args $av"
eval "print_its_args $av"
```

Then:

```
$ sh /tmp/foo -aqval --foo='a  **  b' --abc -- '(moo)'
option -a
option -q with value 'val'
print_its_args  "$2" "$3" "$5"
 {--foo=a  **  b} {--abc} {(moo)}
```

This trick could be used in other [situations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473251/308316); but this is a case where a simpler solution like `set -- "$@" arg` to push args into `$@` cannot be used, because [modifying](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477115/getopts-parse-empty-and-nonempty-args/477124#comment874792_477124) `$@` inside the `getopts` loop cannot be done in a portable way.

Comment: Note that the second option won't be very robust at handling options with values (e.g. `--long-opt='some value'`). As usual, `eval` is a huge source of trouble...

Comment: That's what I was warning about when stating *There is a way to use the bash builtin getopts to mimic long options, but you should not do that as it's a kludge and not worth your effort as **getopts cannot enforce** the long specification.*  It's still elegant code, so not downvoting.

Comment: Please explain how this "does not enforce the long specification". As to the eval + long opts with spaces in them in the 2nd ex, that could be easily worked around by a) using arrays b) using IFS and set -f c) using another **portable** trick that I'll edit in when I get something else than a phone to type on

Comment: @GordonDavisson I've updated the second example with something that should be able to handle that, too.