# getopts for parsing both long and short options

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I already have a script that accepts only SHORT OPTIONS, and I want to extend the same script so as to pass the respective LONG OPTIONS. The existing code is given below.

```
while getopts :t:c: name; do   
   case name
    t) first=$OPTARG;;
    c) second=$OPTARG;;
    *) echo 'Invalid option'; break;;   
   esac 
done 
SHIFT $((OPTIND-1))
```

This works for short options, but how can I extend the same code to allow long option parsing?

Comment: Do the suggestions in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62950/getopt-getopts-or-manual-parsing-what-to-use-when-i-want-to-support-both-shor) help?

Comment: That does not help, as it is using vendor specific enhancements on an outdated utility. `getopt` is outdated since ~1988 and all solutions based on the GNU vendor specific variant are non-portable.

Comment: check related [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/482067/308316)

Comment: Stéphane has a [solution](https://github.com/stephane-chazelas/misc-scripts/blob/master/getopts_long.sh) for this although it's quite --long.

Answer (score 1):

Given the inconsistent options available, I tend to roll my own; e.g.

```bsh
SWITCH=false
VAL=default
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ] ; do
  case "${1}" in
    (-s|--switch) SWITCH=true ;;
    (-v|--value)  VAL="${2}" ; shift ;;
    (-v?*)        VAL="${1#-v}" ;;
    (--value=?*)  VAL="${1#--value=}" ;;
  esac
  shift
done
```

Answer (score -3):

This is simple, but the documentation is only in the `getopt()` man page from Solaris and in the `getopts` documentation from `bosh`:

http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html

scroll down to page 47 in the version from December 2019.

Let me edit your example:

```
while getopts ":t:(test)c:(call)" name; do   
    case $name in
    t) first=$OPTARG;;
    c) second=$OPTARG;;
    :) echo "Missing argument for -$OPTARG"; break;;
    *) echo 'Invalid option'; break;;   
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Note that you may need to quote arguments that contain parenthesis....

This accepts `-c` and `--call`.

Note that this only works with

- bosh, the maintained POSIX enhanced Bourne Shell from schilytools on any OS
- sh ,   the old Bourne Shell on Solaris 10
- ksh93 on any OS

`bosh` in addition also supports UNIX style long options `-long` if `optstring` starts with `()`.

Both, `ksh93` and `bosh` in addition support options that start with `+` if `optstring`starts with a `+`. In such a case, `$name` contains `+c` instead of `c`, if the program has been called with `+c`.

BTW: Only `bosh`supports a method to support long options that have no adjacent short option. See `bosh` man page.

I am the author of schilytools.

Comment: schilytools being your project, correct? Please provide attribution if/when you're the author of a referenced tool; thank you! (I, for one, have been bitten by non-obvious usernames correlating with external projects!)

Comment: Well, I thought this is a well known fact...

Comment: *I* recognize *your* name and project, but I'm just one person among many thousands of registered users and ?millions? of anonymous viewers of the site. A simple "my schilytools project" or "bosh shell that I maintain" would be enough, I think.

Comment: I am not aware of a specific version, but I cannot say whether this feature has been copied from ksh93 to OpenSolaris or vice versa. If that feature is from OpenSolaris, you probably need a ksh93 version that is not from before 2008. BTW: are you using a ksh93 version that comes from the modified redhat sources? I just added a hint to quoting...

Comment: @ilkkachu It works with the ksh93 from debian 10 (93u+ 2012-08-01). It also works with the current "ksh2020" development of ksh93.

Comment: @mosvy, it was just the lack of quoting indeed.